# What does the 'Enable Challenge Mode' check box on the ranked multiplayer Find a Match window refer to?

Tags: supreme-commander-2

The title says it all. How does the Enable Challenge Mode setting affect match finding or multiplayer game play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since found an article ([link](http://www.gamereplays.org/supremecommander2/portals.php?show=news&news_id=603697)) with an explanation of the 'Enable Challenge Mode' check box.  Here is the relevant content:

> ...
>   A normal Ranked 1v1 game has a 1X multiplier, meaning it's worth 1 game when calculating your final rating. 
>   ...
>   In "Challenge Mode," you're increasing the multiplier so the result will count the same as if you played multiple matches against the same opponent.
>   ...
>   A "Challenge" is issued from a button in the scoreboard, which is accessed by pressing F2 during the match. 
>   ...
>   At this point, that [challenged] player's options are to either "Accept" the newly raised stakes or "Forfeit" the match with the previously agreed-to multiplier.